# Infinite dimensional FG-modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

So the way I understand FG-modules is that it is analogous to a vector space defined over a field F with G a basis. However, I encountered a problem given the hypothesis that V is a possibly infinite dimensional FG-module where G is a finite group. I am confused how you can have a FG-module when your "basis" G is finite?

Comment: It seems to me that the question was cleared up by Matt's (+1) answer. To give an example of a non-trivial infinite dimensional module consider the following. Let $G=C_2=\langle g\rangle$ be a cyclic group of order two generated by $g$. Let $F=\Bbb{R}$, and let $V$ be the space of real valued functions on the real line. Let $G$ act on $V$ by the rule
$(g\cdot f)(x)=f(-x)$. Then $g\cdot (g\cdot f)=f$, so this gives $V$ the structure of an $\Bbb{R}[G]$-module. Exercise: Show that $V$ is the direct sum of two subrepresentations consisting of even and odd functions respectively.

Answer (score 3):

What you are describing, if I understand correctly, is not an $F[G]$--module, but rather $F[G]$ itself. An example of an infinite dimensional $F[G]$ module is any infinite dimensional vector space where $G$ acts trivially.

Comment: So, F[G] itself is the vector space structure over F with G a basis, and that acts on some vector space V to give rise to a F[G]-module?

Comment: Yes. $F[G]$ has $G$ as a basis. Normally just $F$ acts on a vector space; a vector space is an $F$ module. It becomes an $F[G]$ module when you also have a linear action of $G$.